# c# Appsettings giving error: The name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, .net, configurationmanager

At the top of my program I have the following :

```
       using System.Configuration;
```

Within my code, I have the following:

```
int  CompanyID = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CompanyId"]
    .ToString());
```

I am getting the following *error* though :

```
The name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the current context
```

I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: You probably could have [googled](http://www.google.com/search?q=The+name+'ConfigurationManager'+does+not+exist+in+the+current+context&aq=f&oq=The+name+'ConfigurationManager'+does+not+exist+in+the+current+context&sugexp=chrome,mod=11&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) yourself an answer to that one. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To expand a bit, you will need to add a reference to `System.Configuration.dll` to get this to work.  It's kind of misleading because the `System.Configuration` namespace also exists inside the base `System.dll`, and holds some far lesser used objects like [`SettingsContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.settingscontext.aspx).  As a result, it seems like it really ought to work, but it doesn't.  It is really confusing, and currently one of those obtuse gotchas in the .NET framework.

Fortunately, `System.Configuration.dll` is in the .NET base framework, so you only need to add a reference by right-clicking on the `References` folder in your project, clicking `Add Reference`, and then finding `System.Configuration` under the `.NET` tab.

After it has been imported into your project, don't forget to add `using System.Configuration` to the top of the code file you intend to use `ConfigurationManager` in.

Comment: Hello, I did what you mentioned: right-clicking on the References folder in your project, clicking Add Reference, and then finding System.Configuration under the .NET tab. But I am still getting the same message. I did the build again as well but same message

Comment: @WebDev Oh christ, good call.  I forgot to include `using System.Configuration` at the top of wherever you're using this.  I always forget that because I use resharper, which allows me to auto-add `using` statements that I'm missing.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a reference to System.Configuration in your project.